# Declaring a public variable across modules

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to establish a variable `LastRow` in Module 1, which can be used in other subs and modules. Below is a simplified version of whats in my actual workbook. 
    - One sub to call the others, 
    - One sub to create a public variable,
    - And another sub in a different module with a formula relying on the variable in `Sub CreateVariable`.

I've already received a lot of help on here and from what I've read online declaring a public variable should be pretty straightforward... but I'm not getting it. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Module 1

```
Sub CallOthers()

Call CreateVariable
Call AddFormula

End Sub
```

Module 1

```
Public LastRow As Long

Sub CreateVariable()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Variance")
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

End Sub
```

Module 2

```
Sub AddFormula()

ws.Range("D2:D" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]-RC[1]"

End Sub
```

Comment: put `Public LastRow As Long` all way at top of module, before any subs

Comment: You also will need to pass the ws as global variable if you are not going to redeclare and set in your `AddFormula` sub.

Comment: Very bad idea. If you mean to *write* to `LastRow` from one place, don't expose it as a global variable like this (consider a `Public Property Get` member that returns it, and keep `LastRow` `Private`). Learn to pass parameters to your procedures instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Module 1

```
Public LastRow As Long
Public ws As Worksheet

Sub CreateVariable()

Set ws = Worksheets("Variance")
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

End Sub
Sub CallOthers()

Call CreateVariable
Call AddFormula

End Sub
```

or as @Mat'sMug said pass as variables

Module 1

```
Sub CallOthers()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Variance")
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Call AddFormula(ws,LastRow)

End Sub
```

Module 2

```
Sub AddFormula(ws As Worksheet, LastRow As Long)

ws.Range("D2:D" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]-RC[1]"

End Sub
```